# java multi threading traffic signal example

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am trying to implement traffic signal in java using multi threading concepts. I want to use synchronization. This is code i have written but it doesn't run according to my expectations :P .. What i am actually doing is taking a variable "a" whose value determines which light should be on at a particular time. For eg: a==0 should give red light.. then red light acquires a lock on "a" and changes the value to a==1 after some interval and then switches on to orange light and the same happens for green light as well ..

Code:

```
    package test;

class Lights implements Runnable {

    int a=0,i,j=25;
    synchronized public void valueA()
    {
        a=a+1;
    }

    public void showLight()
    {
        System.out.println("The Light is "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(i=25;i>=0;i--)
            {
                while(j<=i&&j>=10&&a==0)
                {
                showLight();
            /*some code here that locks the value of "a" for thread 1   
                and keeps it until thread 1 unlocks it! */
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                j--;
                }


            while(j<10&&j>=5&&a==1)
            {

                showLight();
                /*some code here that locks the value of "a" for thread 1   
                and keeps it until thread 1 unlocks it! */
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                j--;
            }


            while(j<5&&j>=0&&a==2)
            {
                showLight();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
            }
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
package test;

public class MainTraffic {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Runnable lights=new Lights();

    Thread one=new Thread(lights);
    Thread two=new Thread(lights);
    Thread three=new Thread(lights);

    one.setName("red");
    two.setName("orange");
    three.setName("green");

    one.start();
    two.start();
    three.start();


}
}
```

Comment: One issue (non related to multithreading) is that each instance of Lights uses an instance `a` field - in other words each of your three lights has its own `a` so they work independently one from another.

Comment: how do i make them to access the same value of a!?

Comment: The simplest way would be to make the variable `a` static - but that's probably not the best solution.

Comment: making it static will solve the problem but i want to use synchronization !

Comment: Even if you make it static, you will need to use proper synchronization to make sure changes made by one thread are visible from the other threads.

Comment: Why do you want to implement your traffic light to be multithreaded? To me a multithreaded model seems to make no sense for a traffic light.

Comment: i know! :P just want to learn multi threading!!

Answer (score 1):

synchronized(this) is not very useful when you have several different instances of the class. Only block that are synchronized on the same object are prevented from running in parallel.

One option would be to pass a common object, perhaps containing the "a" you want them to use, to the Lights constructor and have the threads synchronize on that object.

Comment: i tried using this:

 synchronized public void valueA()

 {
  a=a+1;
 }
and then calling valueA() to increment the value of a after the method has finished executing! But what i want is that one thread makes the red display for 25 sec then ornage for 10 sec and green for 5 sec! and i am not getting it!

Comment: I have edited the code a bit.. ! according to what u said but i am still having problems .. i have commented the line where the problem is!

Comment: @user975234 I've taken a look at the code as posted, and it does not represented the changes I recommended. If you would like help with your edited code, please post it.

Comment: may be i am not able to code ur words.. :| confused as where to use synchronized!

Comment: I suggest going back to your book or tutorial. If you want to prevent two threads from running a block at the same time you need to synchronize the block **on the same object** in all the threads. Each thread has its own Runnable, so you cannot usefully synchronize on that.